# Type casting an array of pointers when using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, typecasting-operator

When I am running the following program it executes just fine:

```
int *a, i=3;
int **arr;
a = &i;
arr = malloc(sizeof(int*));
arr[0] = a;
```

However, malloc returns a void* pointer so it would be prettier to type cast it. I tried `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*))` but I am getting a warning:

> assignment from incompatible pointer type

pointing at the line of typecasting (specifically at the equals sign).
What is the correct type for the specific case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be `(int **)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type should be the same as the pointer you're assigning to. Since you're assigning to `int **arr`, you should cast to `int **`.

```
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

However, it's generally not recommended to cast the result of `malloc()` in C. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In general if you are allocating an object of the type `T` then the returned pointer of a call of malloc should be casted to the type `T *`.

For example

```
T *p = ( T * )malloc( sizeof( T ) );
```

That is you want to obtain a pointer to an object of the type `T`, So the obtained pointer will have the type `T *`.

If the object has for example the type `int *` then the corresponding pointer will have the type `int **`.

In C a pointer to the type void may be assigned to a pointer of any other object type without casting. Sometimes casting in C is used for  self-documenting or to avoid some kinds of errors.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am sorry. I missed the word object.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `int**`, not `int*` because the type of `arr` is `int**`.

Note that the better pattern for an allocation is:

```
arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);
```

It is robust to changes of `arr` type. Moreover it is compact and it avoids repetition. It will automatically detect if `arr` is changed to an array or a non-ponter. The size of an allocation is adjusted automatically as well.

The main problem with `malloc` is not the return type but assuring that the correct number of bytes is allocated.